# Flutter command not found / flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, dart, terminal

What I've tried:
Adding/ editing the .bash_profile.rtf file to where the flutter SDK is contained..
export PATH=/Users/temur/Documents/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin:$PATH

after this, I try to run flutter doctor on terminal I get command not found.

even in the path.

Now, if I just copy+ paste the above command in terminal, it works.
Though, it only works until the terminal is exited.

Any way for terminal to read the bash profile file?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask since I only use Windows currently, which OS are you on? Either way, you can find how to upate the PATH permanently here for linux: [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) and here for macOS [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

Comment: @JuanV I have mac, and I've done that where it says you have to place that in the bash_prfile.rtf file

Comment: Thanks, could you post the contents of your $HOME/.bashrc (or $HOME/.zshrc for Catalina) on your question?

Comment: this is my out put for trying to set $HOME. Though, it resets everytime I exit terminal

Comment: temur@Temurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which flutter
flutter not found
temur@Temurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % source $HOME/.bash_profile
temur@Temurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which flutter             
/Users/temur/Documents/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin/flutter
temur@Temurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor

Comment: Yes, it will be gone if you set it like that. You have to open the .bashrc file with a text editor and add (export PATH="$PATH:=/Users/temur/Documents/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin") then save the file, then the next time you open a new terminal it should be available.

Comment: hmm its still the same case

Comment: To get help, I recommend you edit your original question and post the contents of your bashrc file to see exactly what you added.

Comment: in my bash profile file:  export PATH="$PATH:/Users/temur/Documents/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out;
entered command: echo $PATH

spit out;
**/Users/temur/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin**:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

which was different than the one that should be in my .bash_profile

**/Users/temur/Documents/Projects/Flutter/tools/flutter/bin**

Had to change this in my bash profile file.

Also, reverting my terminal to bash from zsh helped.